# how to select a word in android textview

Tags: android, textview

how can i get the exact value of the specific word in a textview when:
1 - the user had taped the word (the word can be just one of many in some text chunk),
2 - the textview has in its xml layout, android:textIsSelectable="true" ,
so by default android lets the user to highlight a specific word 
and opens a small menu(copy, paste, share). can i manipulate this menu or maybe add more options to it in order to extend it and do something i want with the highlighted word?

i need to get the exact word based on some interaction with the user(click , tap, select....)

i didn't find any straight forward answer. is it even possible?

(i have android htc one x)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A more suitable component to use for your scenario is `EditText`.

It is declared like this in your manifest file:

```
<EditText 
android:text=" This is not an editable EditText" 
android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:textColor = "@android:color/white"
android:editable = "false"
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background = "@android:drawable/dark_header">
</EditText>
```

Then, it is only two lines of code to get the selected text:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
String selectedText = et.getText().substring(et.getSelectionStart(), et.getSelectionEnd());
```

Here, we assumed that the text was selected from left to right. If it was selected from right to left, then above would result in an exception so you can avoid that by checking if start position is higher than the end position.